# ALL_LOG_GROUPS did not contain information about tables that are accessible to the current user

Tags: oracle, view

I created some user and connected to oracle with this user(user_privlgs). Also I add grants to select some table that is located another schema:

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <another user>.APITEST_1 TO user_privlgs;
  GRANT SELECT ON <another user>.APITEST_1 TO user_privlgs;
  GRANT UPDATE ON <another user>.APITEST_1 TO user_privlgs;
 GRANT ALTER ON <another user>.APITEST_1 TO user_privlgs;
```

DDL of table:

```
CREATE TABLE <another user>."APITEST_1"
   (    "ID" NUMBER,
    "COLUM_1" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    "COLUM_2" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
     SUPPLEMENTAL LOG DATA (ALL) COLUMNS
   ) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
```

Table has information about supplemental logs.

And tried select data from ALL_LOG_GROUPS , but there are no inormation about .APITEST_1.
And in oracle site
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1094.htm#i1581389
written that - ALL_LOG_GROUPS describes the log group definitions on the tables accessible to the current user. But this ."APITEST_1" is assessible to the user user_privlgs...
 Do you know what kind of grants needed to select data of  .APITEST_1 from ALL_LOG_GROUPS ?

Comment: So are you using Oracle version 10.2, or a different one?  So can a `sysdba` user display information for "<another user>" for `APITEST_1` table in `DBA_LOG_GROUPS`?

Comment: I used 12.2 version, yes I can use DBA_LOG_GROUPS, but I need ALL_LOG_GROUPS. If I set grant select any table, when ALL_LOG_GROUPS shows info about APITEST_1, but I cannot use this very wide permission...

Answer (score 2):

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON table_name TO user` should be enough for the granted user to access `ALL_LOG_GROUPS` row for `table_name` connected as `user`.

I cannot reproduce your issue with oracle 19c.

```
SQL> select banner from v$version where rownum=1;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

SQL> --
SQL> create user privuser identified by privuser;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to privuser;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> --
SQL> create user anotheruser identified by anotheruser;

User created.

SQL> alter user anotheruser quota unlimited on users;

User altered.

SQL> grant create session, create table to anotheruser;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> --
SQL> connect anotheruser/anotheruser
Connected.

Session altered.

SQL> show user;
USER is "ANOTHERUSER"
SQL> CREATE TABLE apitest
  2  (    ID NUMBER,
  3       COLUM_1 VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  4       COLUM_2 VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
  5       SUPPLEMENTAL LOG DATA (ALL) COLUMNS
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> 
SQL> select owner, log_group_name, table_name
  2  from user_log_groups
  3  where table_name='APITEST';

OWNER            LOG_GROUP_NAME   TABLE_NAME
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
ANOTHERUSER      SYS_C007872      APITEST

SQL> grant all privileges on apitest to privuser;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> --
SQL> connect privuser/privuser;
Connected.

Session altered.

SQL> show user
USER is "PRIVUSER"
SQL> select owner, log_group_name, table_name
  2  from all_log_groups
  3  where table_name='APITEST';

OWNER            LOG_GROUP_NAME   TABLE_NAME
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
ANOTHERUSER      SYS_C007872      APITEST

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you very much! these table has been recreated by another person without supplemental group, I tried set this grant eralier, but table has not supplemental data because table has been recreated...